# Какая организация в России занимается стандартизацией языка C (не C++)?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

У меня на работе разгорелась дискуссия о том будет ли результат функции `snprintf` содержать terminating null character, если полный результат не помещается в выходной буфер.
Анализ привел вот к [этому моему ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498477/6362941), и некоторые люди (не имеющие отношения к стандартизации) высказали *согласие*, что в Стандарте языка Си есть некая неоднозначность.
В стремлении устранить неоднозначность я задал [вот этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515162/snprintf-are-there-any-c-standard-proposals-plans-to-change-the-description-of) и получил [вот такой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50524523/6362941). Понял, что
* работы по устранению этой неоднозначности (из Стандарта) *не ведутся*,
* свои предложения в *международный* стандарт надо проталкивать через *национальный* орган стандартизации (языка Си). В моем случае таких органов два: Российский и [Американский](http://standards.incits.org/a/public/group/pl22.11).

Вот и спрашиваю: "Какая организация в России занимается стандартизацией языка C (не C++)?".

(Для меня это первый случай, когда у меня есть конкретные мысли об изменениях в каком-либо Стандарте)

---

Хочу,
* во-первых, узнать мнение более опытных людей, видят ли они тоже неоднозначность, и, если да, то
* во-вторых, узнать, что нужно сделать, чтобы выдвинуть Defect Report для Стандарта Си,
* в-третьих, если моя точка зрения достаточно обоснована, то выдвинуть Defect Report как через Российский национальный орган стандартизации языка Си так и через [Американский](http://standards.incits.org/a/public/group/pl22.11) (а коллега, с которым была дискуссия, возможно, попытается через органы стандартизации Словакии).

Comment: Какие дискуссии, когда в [man snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) ясно написано -- *`"The  functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() do not write more than size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0'))."`*?

Comment: на практике snprintf сам не добавляет '\0', приходиться это делать ручками.

Comment: @NewView, видимо вам здорово не повезло с ОС (средой программирования)

Comment: Да, да :) CentOs 6 чтоли, есть в хозяйстве, там он реализован именно с таким багом :) неожиданно обнаружил.. snprintf не часто используем

Comment: @NewView, причём тут версия дистрибутива, если важна версия libc (и сам компилятор, но маловероятно). А без примера тяжело в такое поверить.

Comment: @avp, этот `man` всё же идёт с конкретной реализацией libc и не является аргументом в кровавых разборках по вопросу «как всё может быть в сферической libc в вакууме». ИМХО проблема уходит корнями в один популярный компилятор для одной популярной кое-как-бы-POSIX ОС, который не реализовывал C99 и в котором раньше не было `snprintf`, но была `_snprintf`, которая пишет все `n` символов и не завершала строку нулём...

Comment: @RobinKuzmin честно говоря, не вижу ни какого разночтения...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, но все же в этом мане ссылочка `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L` на стандарт есть

Comment: @avp, в секции `Conforming To` прямым текстом написано, что соответствует C99, но это значит только то что функция ведёт себя так как **допускает** стандарт, но не значит, что стандарт **требует** именно такого поведения, а не оставляет его на усмотрение реализации... обычно в glibc'шных манах такое оговорено, но паранойя не позволяет на это полагаться, а в темах с меткой `language-lawyer` последнее слово всегда за священным Стандартом =)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ладно, ... с этим стандартом. imho любая разумная реализация (на всякий случай заглянул в [musl](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vsnprintf.c)) должна этот 0 ставить

Comment: @avp, с этим ИМХО ни кто не спорит =)... разве что *NewView* на какой-то баг в centOS'е напарывался, но я после быстрого гугления по багзиллам не нашёл ни каких следов такового...